# How to call other macros from a Chicken Scheme macro?

Tags: macros, scheme, chicken-scheme, define-syntax

I'm trying to move from Common Lisp to [Chicken Scheme](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFjeiF87DOAhWnLsAKHSUgCDEQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.call-cc.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFDmteacdlGk5n8AqHTv2_PAJ8gCw&sig2=ClzySj1QooMSl8dw6IhXUA), and having plenty of problems.

My current problem is this: How can I write a macro (presumably using `define-syntax`?) that calls other macros?

For example, in Common Lisp I could do something like this:

```
(defmacro append-to (var value)
 `(setf ,var (append ,var ,value)))

(defmacro something-else ()
 (let ((values (list))
  (append-to values '(1)))))
```

Whereas in Scheme, the equivalent code doesn't work:

```
(define-syntax append-to
 (syntax-rules ()
  ((_ var value)
   (set! var (append var value)))))

(define-syntax something-else
 (syntax-rules ()
  ((_)
   (let ((values (list)))
    (append-to values '(1))))))
```

The `append-to` macro cannot be called from the `something-else` macro. I get an error saying the `append-to` "variable" is undefined.

According to all the information I've managed to glean from Google and other sources, macros are evaluated in a closed environment without access to other code. Essentially, nothing else exists - except built-in Scheme functions and macros - when the macro is evaluated. I have tried using `er-macro-transformer`, `syntax-case` (which is now deprecated in Chicken anyway) and even the `procedural-macros` module.

Surely the *entire purpose* of macros is that they are built upon *other* macros, to avoid repeating code. If macros must be written in isolation, they're pretty much useless, to my mind.

I have investigated other Scheme implementations, and had no more luck. Seems it simply cannot be done.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Doing anything more complex than `syntax-rules` macros is non-standard Scheme, so while what you want to do is quite possible in many *specific* Schemes, the way to do it will likely vary wildly between them. If you want to ask this sort of question, it’d probably be better to pick a specific Scheme implementation and ask about how to replicate it in that.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thanks, I have modified my question to focus more on one implementation.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Maybe you can give a Common Lisp example that you're unable to get to work with CHICKEN?

Comment: @sjamaan I have added a Common Lisp example.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot clearer now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing expansion-time with run-time. The `syntax-rules` example you give will *expand* to the let+set, which means the append will happen at runtime.

`syntax-rules` simply rewrites input to given output, expanding macros until there's nothing more to expand.  If you want to actually perform some computation at expansion time, the only way to do that is with a procedural macro (this is also what happens in your `defmacro` CL example).

In Scheme, evaluation levels are strictly separated (this makes separate compilation possible), so a procedure can use macros, but the macros themselves can't use the procedures (or macros) defined in the same piece of code.  You can load procedures and macros from a module for use in procedural macros by using [use-for-syntax](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20macros%20and%20special%20forms#use-for-syntax).  There's limited support for defining things to run at syntax expansion time by wrapping them in [begin-for-syntax](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20macros%20and%20special%20forms#begin-for-syntax).

See for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123063/arbitrary-computation-in-scheme-macro) or [this discussion on the ikarus-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ikarus-users/7Fea07YZ8tU). Matthew Flatt's paper [composable and compilable macros](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/macromod.pdf) explains the theory behind this in more detail.

The "phase separation" thinking is relatively new in the Scheme world (note that the Flatt paper is from 2002), so you'll find quite a few people in the Scheme community who are still a bit confused about it.  The reason it's "new" (even though Scheme has had macros for a long long time) is that procedural macros have only become part of the standard since R6RS (and reverted in R7RS because `syntax-case` is rather controversial), so the need to rigidly specify them hasn't been an issue until now. For more "traditional" Lispy implementations of Scheme, where compile-time and run-time are all mashed together, this was never an issue; you can just run code whenever.

To get back to your example, it works fine if you separate the phases correctly:

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax append-to
    (ir-macro-transformer
      (lambda (e i c)
        (let ((var (cadr e))
              (val (caddr e)))
          `(set! ,var (append ,var ,val)))))) )

(define-syntax something-else
  (ir-macro-transformer
    (lambda (e i c)
      (let ((vals (list 'print)))
        (append-to vals '(1))
        vals))))

(something-else) ; Expands to (print 1)
```

If you put the definition of `append-to` in a module of its own, and you `use-for-syntax` it, that should work as well.  This will also allow you to use the same module both in the macros you define in a body of code as well as in the procedures, by simply requiring it both in a `use` **and** a `use-for-syntax` expression.

Comment: That was a very useful reply, thanks. So... kinda like [this](http://pastebin.com/weP9GnR1) then?

Comment: Yep. However, in that particular example you don't need to use an er-macro-transformer of course. That's only required if you need to perform side-effects or want to construct identifiers or constants at compile-time. (in cases where you only need to pattern-match and rearrange input expressions, you can just use `syntax-rules`)